# Oracle Spatial dump Transformation

Tags: oracle-spatial

I have received an Oracle Spatial dump (.dmp) from an external source, but lack access to an Oracle Spatial DB. Is there an open-source way to extract the data? ogr2ogr seems to work with a running db only.

Comment: You can install Oracle XE for free. Install the dump and convert data into some open format with ogr2ogr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to read an Oracle dump file is a fully functional Oracle installation.

Note that there are **two different types** of dump files:

- The "old" format, produced by the `exp` tool. This needs to be imported using the `imp` tool.
- The normal format, produced by the `expdp` (aka "Data Pump") tool. This is imported using the `impdp` tool.

Nothing distinguishes one from the other externally, but you can find out by looking at the strings at the start of the file:

Here is how an "old-style" dmp file looks like:

```
$ strings base_data.dmp | head
gEXPORT:V19.00.00
USCOTT
RTABLES
1024
                                       Tue Jun 8 10:20:38 2021base_data.dmp
#G#G
#G#G
+00:00
BYTE
UNUSED
```

Here is how a normal "expdp" dump file looks like:

```
$ strings spatial.dmp | head
"SYSTEM"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01"
x86_64/Linux 2.4.xx
ORCLCDB
AL32UTF8
19.00.00.00.00
001:001:000001:000001
HDR>T<?
E)U4=OP
LM11110&A
```

Each import command (`imp` or `impdp`) also has options for showing the content of the file in terms of schemas, tables, indexes etc it contains.

Use `imp help=y` or `impdp help=y` to find out about the command syntax and options.